# Is there a way to export an animation without rendering?

Tags: animation, export

I would like to export my animation, but as if it were in studio mode. Rendering the whole animation takes too long and I don't want it shaded that way.

Comment: Hello ! I don't think so. Maybe you mean without rendering with Eevee or Cycles ? You can use the OpenGL renderer to quickly render a viewport animation. Would that be okay ?

Comment: Where/what are you trying to export your animation into?  Another program such as Unreal or an image viewer? If it's something like Unreal, Blender supports various export formats such as FBX which include armature animation data. If it's just an image viewer of some sort you'll have to render it frame by frame into the required video format file.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by 'export'?

Comment: This question needs clarifiaction.. If you can specify where you'd like to export to, or the formats you are considering, then we can re-open it.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is of course: no, you can't.

But depending on what you mean:
If you don't want to render the animation using neither `Cycles` nor `EEVEE` rendering engine, just to have a look at the animation, you can still use the `Workbench` rendering engine which gives you the fast viewport rendering.

[image: Workbench render engine]

In the render panel inside the properties window, choose `Workbench`as your render engine.
It does have its own settings, and you will have access to some features like matcap rendering here too. This should be the fastes way to go, but technicaly, even a view in the viewport is  rendered output, so, yes, if you want to see something, it's rendered.

See the [`Workbench`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/workbench/introduction.html) section in the documentation.

There it says:

> The Workbench Engine is a render engine optimized for fast rendering during modeling and animation preview. It is not intended to be a render engine that will render final images for a project. Its primary task is to display a scene in the 3D Viewport when it is being worked on.